# How to use dplyr to make modifications in a dataframe equivalent to the use of a 'which'?

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have a data frame, say

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(2, 4, 7), z = c(3, 6, 10))
```

then I can modify entries with the `which` function:

```
w <- which(df[,"y"] == 7)
df[w,c("y", "z")] <- data.frame(6, 9)
```

One way I see to do this with the package dplyr is the following:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(W = (y==7), 
         y = ifelse(W, 6, y), 
         z = ifelse(W, 9, z)) %>%
  select(-W)
```

But I find it a bit unelegant, and I am not so sure it would replace all kinds of `which` uses. Ideally I would imagine something like:

```
df <- df %>% 
  keep(y == 7) %>%
  mutate(y = 6) %>%
  unkeep()
```

where `keep` would *provisionally* select rows where modifications are to be made, and `unkeep` would unselect them to recover the full data frame.

Comment: You might want to double-check exactly what your original code is doing. Hint: see happens if you want to modify 3 rows.

Comment: @HongOoi: Thanks, I have changed `c(6, 9)` for `data.frame(6, 9)`.